# verify login and login type using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm still new in asp.net.. i hv been assigned a task to verify login using C# ASP.NET with two Login button which is Login for members and Login for Admin..Can you help me on how to connect my dbo.users table field in database with below login code and give the status for the login either Active or not.

Answer (score 2):

Asp.net provides various methods of authentication. It is usually best to select one of the existing authentication mechanisms.

In your case forms authentication would work best.
Asp.net provides a login control for this.
It has events you can hook on to do custom checking with own tables.

Here are a few links to get you started.

[Forms authentication overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[Login controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[Asp.net membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would also to @nunespascal's answer that you wouldn't need two logins for users and admins if you used Forms Authentication as you could simply check to see which role the user was in after authentication.  Then based on that you take whatever action is necessary.

Comment: thanks @Jeremy Lattimore..i'd ask my supervisor if i can use 1 login but she still wants 2 logins for users and admins.